# Attempting to build out an extension, but keep getting an error about missing id's?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

Here is the console error I am getting that is preventing me from accessing the DOM. I can verify the id exists, not sure if this is some kind of security function: \<![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","hidden_elem"]]]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook, which this error seems to be associated with, doesn't actually use the jQuery library. If you run `jQuery` in your console, you will get an error. The `$` shortcut is actually a selector for another library. This is why you are getting an error.

[image: jQuery]

You can use a content script to inject the jQuery library into the web page, via a `script` tag:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('path_to_jquery/jQuery.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

You will then be able to use jQuery on the page itself, using `jQuery('#id')`. You can define a new shortcut for it using:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq('#id'); // using the new shortcut
```

You can also use jQuery to access the DOM, by including jQuery as a content script, along with your other script. The following goes in `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.4.min.js", "your_script.js"]
```

In `your_script.js`, you should be able to use jQuery as normal, as the context is different from the actual page's, so there is no conflict with the `$` variable. You can set the `console` context to the extension by changing `top` to the extension itself.

Comment: Do you by chance have a means for this to utilize just with the console, for testing purposes? Would I just swap out the "chrome.extension.getURL('path_to_jquery/jQuery.js');" portion with a cdn?

Comment: Another thing is, even when using things like "document.getElementsByClassName("_xd7").style.color = "red"; " I receive cannot set property of undefined error.

Comment: @BrandonKorenek If you just want to just test in the console quickly, just get a copy of the minified jQuery library and run it into the console, and then just use `jQuery()`. If you want to have it permanently in the page, use the first method I showed, and you can either use the CDN or have it packed in the extension itself.

Comment: @BrandonKorenek `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements, so you must loop through to modify the styles of each element. To access the first, access it at index 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything is working. I think what may have been messing me up in conjunction with the class situation was that I there was a little bit of a delay when attempting to read the DOM. After I let the window stay idle for about 10 seconds it allowed be to change it via getElementById();